# Empty angular array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes, which are dynamically built from `getJson` request.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in relatedServices | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search:strict">
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="array[$index]" ng-true-value="{{value.ID}}" ng-false-value="{{undefined}}" />
 </td>
<tr>
```

Then I would like to check some checkboxes and `postJSON` them.

Here is controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


    myApp.controller('JsonController', function ($http, $scope) {


        $http.get("/RS/GETJSON/")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.relatedServices = response;
        });

        $scope.array = [];

        var values = $scope.array;
        var log = [];

        angular.forEach(values, function (value, key) {
            this.push('{Id' + ': ' + value + '}');
        }, log);


        $scope.add = function () {
            $http.post("/RS/POSTJSON/", log);
        }

    });
```

The problem is when I check the checkboxes, values are `$scoped` to the `$scope.array = [];`.

But when I run `add()`, the `log = []` are empty.

How ever if I hardcode values in the script, lets say

```
$scope.array = ['1','2','3'];
```

This values do not disappear.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is timing, the $http.get is called but the success part is only called once the data is returned. In the meantime execution continues and when you do the forEach $scope.array is still empty. You can move the forEach into the add function but you should also check to see if the data has actually been returned.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('JsonController', function ($http, $scope) {

    var hasLoaded = false;

    $http.get("/RS/GETJSON/")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.relatedServices = response;
        hasLoaded = true;
   });

   $scope.array = [];

   $scope.add = function () {
       if(!hasLoaded) {
           alert('Still waiting');
           return;
       }

       var values = $scope.array;
       var log = [];

       angular.forEach(values, function (value, key) {
          this.push('{Id' + ': ' + value + '}');
       }, log);


       $http.post("/RS/POSTJSON/", log);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's work for me!
I wasn't even thinking about it.
I am only 3 with AngularJS